# passing date argument to store date in object variable in c#

Tags: c#

how can i initialize t1 object which has start and end dates as parameters? the error line is t1.store("task1","gui design",2014 01 01,2014 04 04,"completed") . how can i pass date argument to store method... can anyone help me to find out?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t1 = new Task();
        Task t2 = new Task();
        t1.store("task1","gui design",2014 01 01,2014 04 04,"completed");
    }
}

class Task 
{
    string _Tid;
    string _tn;
    DateTime _sdate;
    DateTime _edate;
    string _status;
    public void store(string tid,string tname, Date start,Date end,string sts) 
    {
        this._Tid = tid;
        this._tn = tname;
        this._sdate = start;
        this._edate = end;
        this._status = sts;
    }
    public void print() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n {0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",this._Tid,this._tn,this._sdate,this._edate,this._status);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That depends entirely on what `Date` is and what constructors it provides. There's no way anyone here can answer this question. Most likely it involves code like `new Date(...)`, and then you have to figure out how to put the values you have into the parameters to that constructor.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. `Date` is not a built-in .NET type. This type either comes from your own code, or from a library you're using, but unless we either know which library it came from, or can see the code for its constructor(s), there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: yes i am using 'Date' from library https://github.com/claycephus/csharp-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create DateTime via these methods

```
            var dt1 = new DateTime(2014,10,25);
            var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2014/10/25");
```

and change the method signature to this

```
public void store(string tid,string tname, DateTime start,DateTime end,string sts)
```

and if you want to be sure that you only use the Date part of DateTime object you can use start.Date or end.Date

Comment: He's not using `DateTime`, he's using `Date`, which is not a .NET type, there's no way anyone here can answer his question.

Comment: So what is the question? Surely you can see the constructor for Date there? What happens if you type `new Date(`, do you get help from Visual Studio telling you what goes where?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ` public void store(string tid, string tname, DateTime start, DateTime end,` the definition of parameters is `DateTime` so he would need a DateTime object as param

Comment: @RezaRahmati No, the definition of the parameters is `Date`, not `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

```
t1.store("task1","gui design",Convert.ToDateTime(01/01/2014),Convert.ToDateTime(04/04/2014),"completed");
```

Answer (score 0):

your parameter is incorrect.
you must use this figure:
new Date(2014 01 01) and  pass tow method;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Task t1 = new Task();
         Task t2 = new Task();
         t1.store("task1","gui design",new DateTime(2014, 01, 01),new DateTime(2014 ,04 ,04),"completed");
    }
}

class Task
{
    string _Tid;
    string _tn;
    DateTime _sdate;
    DateTime _edate;
    string _status;

    public void store(string tid, string tname, DateTime start, DateTime end, string sts)
    {
        this._Tid = tid;
        this._tn = tname;
        this._sdate = start;
        this._edate = end;
        this._status = sts;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n {0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", this._Tid, this._tn, this._sdate, this._edate, this._status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a [custom `Date` implementation](https://github.com/claycephus/csharp-date), the correct way to call that method is like this:

```
t1.store("task1","gui design", new Date(2014, 01, 01), new Date(2014, 04, 04) ,"completed");
```